# Google Spreadsheet: Query function date formatting not working

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I'm trying to make this query work on my spreadsheet on chrome Win7:

```
=QUERY(A1:D5;"SELECT MAX(A), COUNT(A), SUM(C) 
              GROUP BY (A) FORMAT MAX(A) 'MMMM' ")
```

Everything is ok except for the format part.
I'd like my date to show just as a month name but it shows exactly in the standard way (dd/MM/YYYY).

I would like to point out that neither a simple query like

```
=QUERY(A1:D5;"SELECT A FORMAT A 'MMMM'")
```

displays the dates in the wanted format =\

What am I doing wrong? The document I'm working on is this: [BENZINA](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AoK7IdGDwVMPdHMtNW5WWGQ0ZU93aWZTTGFtbzhOdkE&usp=sharing)

Comment: If you use this formula, then all blank row are ignored: `=QUERY(A:E;"SELECT B, COUNT(A), SUM(D) WHERE D IS NOT NULL GROUP BY B")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible. The `QUERY` documentation is primarily meant for the Google Visualization API and not the `QUERY` function in Google Spreadsheet. Read the following thread from the Google Product Forum: [QUERY FORMAT](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/YnkXpXCD4rI).

What you could do instead, is to create a second column, containing the date format you want: `MONTH(A2)`.

Comment: In the Documentation for the QUERY function of the Spreadsheet there's a link to the Google Visualization API and it says to follow the guidelines written there. [Reference for Query Funtion](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1388882). I've thought about the second column but it would have been better if I could keep just one.

Comment: @AndreaSilvestri Answer remains the same. Did it help you?

Comment: well.... sort of